# create webview on top of the other layouts which fits to screen

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

Can I create a WebView on top of all the other layouts dynamically?

Actually I want to have WebView on the top of all the layout and which fits to the screen?

I am using `LinearLayout`. Can I do this using code ?

Comment: Just add the webview in your xml layout on the right place. Then in your code you only have to set the visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `FrameLayout` and place your `LinearLayout` and `WebView` in it.
Since in `FrameLayout` Child views are drawn in a stack. you will have both the views overlapping on each other. control their visibility to switch between your views.